# mySql Join two tables on non unique columns

Tags: mysql, join

Hi have the following tables:

table districts:

```
id   DD   text   
---|----|-----
1  | 01 | texas     
2  | 02 | ny     
5  | 03 | washington
```

table councils:

```
id   DD   CC   text
---|----|----|-----
1  | 01 | 01 | text1 
2  | 02 | 01 | text2
5  | 02 | 02 | text3
3  | 02 | 03 | text4
4  | 03 | 01 | text5
5  | 03 | 02 | text6
6  | 01 | 02 | text7
```

table person:

```
id   name    DD   CC
---|-------|----|----
1  | john  | 02 | 03 
2  | mike  | 03 | 02
3  | julia | 01 | 02
```

I want to make a query so I get the following result:

result:

```
 name     District    Council
-------|------------|-------
 john  | ny         | text4 
 mike  | washington | text6
 julia | texas      | text7
```

So far I have the following query:

```
select p.name,d.text as district,c.text as council
    from  person p 
        inner join districts d on p.DD=d.DD
        inner join councils c on p.DD=c.DD and p.CC=c.CC
where 1;
```

I think that the logic should be correct but somehow I'm getting an error... Can anyone help understand this or point me in the right direction??

If I do this it returns results but not the expected of course:

```
select p.name,d.text as district,c.text as council
    from  person p 
        inner join districts d on p.DD=d.DD
        inner join councils c on p.CC=c.id
where 1;
```

Thanks

EDIT: It was a collation problem... My advice if you find this is to not use query browser 'cause errors are not very verbose... There might be an option in it but I dont't know!

Thank you all

Comment: whats the error you're getting?

Comment: Wild guess: Is the table `person` or `persons` ?

Comment: Another possible problem: Are the joined fields of the same type?

Comment: Thanks for the replies!!

The error is "The query could not be executed" (not very helping)

the fields are all the same type Varchar(32)

Comment: The table names are correct. if i replace p.CC=c.id the query works but doesn't give the expected result!!

Comment: Have you tried running it in Query Browser or WorkBench or phpMyAdmin? How are you running it?

Comment: Query Browser... Just an update to last post... it only works if i do as seen in the post (last query).

Comment: Tested it in workbench and got a much more verbose error... Matter of fact it was the collation of some fields that didn't mach!! Thank you all

Comment: @User691553: which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had no idea of your schema, but here's what I did (and it works fine!)

```
CREATE TABLE `districts` (
    `id` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `DD` CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `text` CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `councils` (
    `id` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `DD` CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `CC` CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `text` CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `person` (
    `id` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `DD` CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `CC` CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `name` CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO districts (`id`, `DD`, `text`) VALUES ('1','01','texas');   
INSERT INTO districts (`id`, `DD`, `text`) VALUES ('2','02','ny');   
INSERT INTO districts (`id`, `DD`, `text`) VALUES ('5','03','washington');

INSERT INTO councils (`id`, `DD`, `CC`, `text`) VALUES ('1','01','01','text1');
INSERT INTO councils (`id`, `DD`, `CC`, `text`) VALUES ('2','02','01','text2');
INSERT INTO councils (`id`, `DD`, `CC`, `text`) VALUES ('3','02','03','text4');
INSERT INTO councils (`id`, `DD`, `CC`, `text`) VALUES ('4','03','01','text5');
INSERT INTO councils (`id`, `DD`, `CC`, `text`) VALUES ('5','03','02','text6');
INSERT INTO councils (`id`, `DD`, `CC`, `text`) VALUES ('6','01','02','text7');

INSERT INTO person (`id`, `name`, `DD`, `CC`) VALUES ('1','john','02','03');
INSERT INTO person (`id`, `name`, `DD`, `CC`) VALUES ('2','mike','03','02');
INSERT INTO person (`id`, `name`, `DD`, `CC`) VALUES ('3','julia','01','02');

SELECT p.name, d.text AS district, c.text AS council
FROM person p
INNER JOIN districts d ON p.DD = d.DD
INNER JOIN councils c ON p.DD = c.DD
AND p.CC = c.CC
WHERE 1
```

Comment: Tested it in workbench and got a much more verbose error... Matter of fact it was the collation of some fields that didn't mach!! Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Your first query SHOULD have worked... only remove the WHERE 1... you don't need the where clause at all if you are returning all records from the "person" table.  Your table alias use is correct, and the first query properly joins to the councils on both district and council, otherwise your second sample query would return multiple rows for a person since there are duplicate "council" codes only.

The "WHERE 1" is failing...  as 1 is not a logical expression... If used, you would have to do "WHERE 1=1"

Comment: `WHERE 1` validates as `WHERE True` in MySQL. And so is `WHERE 2`, `WHERE 3`, etc...

Comment: @ypercube, thanks for correcting me on that (for my future use)... However, I don't ever use a wasted where clause such as the one applied here where all records are expected to be returned... And if a numeric value, I would always explicitly put the operational compare against it.

Comment: I've mosyly seen it used when building dynamic queries with PHP or other languages. First create the `SELECT ... WHERE 1=1` and then add any constraints `AND constr1` , `AND constr2`, etc... Just to skip an IF-ELSE in the code.